# Using a Custom Form as Hamburger SideMenu on Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have seen the Codename One Video on how to create a Codename One Hamburger Side Menu using Commands.

I have been trying to see if I can do that on a button click instead (my forms have title bars turned off, i use a border layout and create my own title bar by placing it in the North), with probably another from as the side menu. I would like to have an image and then a custom menu display on my Side Menu instead of the regular Codename One buttons.

Has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the `Toolbar` class which is more powerful and would probably alleviate the need to override the title area:

http://codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_toolbar

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/cats-in-toolbars

You can't set a form at the side menu but you can add arbitrary components into it which should be enough. Again the Toolbar API makes this rather simple.

Comment: Hi @shai-almog, thanks for the feedbak. The toolbar is really helpful but I have an issue with adding components. I tried this snippet:   Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
        f.setToolBar(toolbar);             ...     Label sideHeaderLabel = new Label("Test");
            sideHeaderLabel.setUIID("HeaderContainer");
            sideHeaderLabel.setIcon(fetchResourceFile().getImage("logo.fw.png"));
            
            toolbar.addComponentToSideMenu(sideHeaderLabel); .... when i click on the hamburger icon, the sidemenu shows but the component doesn't show, am I missing something?

Comment: Yea. I did. I also noticed commands dont seem to show on the side menu. I dont know if its a themeing problem but I had used a custome theme for the label so at least that should show properly

Comment: Hi @shai-almog, i got it to work. I don't know why but I had to set the constant sideMenuShadowBool to false before the components and commands started showing. Thanks